# Bookmark time stamp video player for Android

Tags: bookmarks, gestures, android-video-player, timestamp, asl

I want to make an Android app that will let me bookmark a video file by time stamp
example bookmark1 00:00:00 = bookmarkname else if bookmark2 = 00:20:01 = bookmarkname2 
I also want this video player app to support gestures, no audio needed only video.

If anyone can help me with the code on this or know if there is an app that already can do this please let me know.

also a video player for android that can recognize chapter markers embedded in a m4v file
might do the trick

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help. I utilize "mvideoplayer", and have created many bookmark files.

FYI--the chapter markers in m4v are not embedded. They are actually in a text file separate from the video file. These text files contain time markers (with "titles" indicating what is located at those particular time locations).

Also, since you need video only (no audio), do you happen to need this for sign language videos?

Comment: don't put your email address in here